# JPA 2 query giving strange behavior on OR clause

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA 2 query that is driving me nuts.  A SurveyQuestion may have an Organization.  Here's the mapping within SurveyQuestion

```
@ManyToOne( optional=true )
@JoinColumn( name="organization_key" )
private Organization organization;
```

Organization has a field named key.  I create a TypedNamedQuery with the following jpql

```
SELECT q from SurveyQuestion q 
    where q.organization IS NULL 
    or q.organization.key = :organizationKey
```

with that query I only get the questions that have the given key.  If I remove the q.organization.key = :organizationKey from the query, then I get all those that have no organization, but I can't for the life of me get it to return the combination of those that have no organization or have the given organization.

JPA2 with EclipseLink provider.

Comment: can the problem take place because `KEY` is a keyword in JPA2? http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/jpql#Feature_design

Comment: hrm, perhaps, but if I remove the IS NULL qualification, then I can get all those questions that have the given organization.  I just can't get the combination of both at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is JPA standard.

```
q.organization.key
```

resolves to an inner join on q.organization, not to a left join!

You have to do this:

```
SELECT q 
  from SurveyQuestion q 
  left join q.organization o
 where o is null OR o.key = :organizationKey
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. This is what I get for loaning my excellent JPA book to a friend.  As is, your query behaves the same as mine due to the "where q.organization is null"  I had to change that to "where o is null" otherwise I believe the q.organization in your where clause was causing the same behavior as mine.  That said, due to your suggestion I had it fixed in 10 minutes this morning.  Thanks again.